# convert c# Encryption Rfc2898DeriveBytes to java

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I am trying to implement the following code in java application

```
private const string ENCRYPTION_KEY="MAKSQYV2SPBUIRDHKJDU243NI99212";
   public  string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = ENCRYPTION_KEY;
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

As of now I am using this following code in my Java project, but it returns wrong result can any body help me out on this problem

```
public String encryption(String clearText) throws Exception {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(clearText.toCharArray(),
            new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64,
                    0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 }, 1000, 384);
    Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    byte[] key = new byte[32];
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 0, key, 0, 32);
    System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 32, iv, 0, 16);

    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    String result = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(secret.getEncoded()));
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    return result;
}
```